# spring boot responseEntity best pratices

Tags: java, spring-boot, architecture

I wrote a controller in Spring Boot that calls a third-party API and gets a set of data from it. In addition to the various parameters, the third-party API requires a geographic point (latitude and longituine) and returns certain weather data from the given location:

```
{
    "latitude": 50.51,
    "longitude":-113.27,
    "models": ["gem_hrdps_continental"],
    "hourly":["temperature_2m"]
}
```

I modified this by using a List instead of Doubles to have a JSON that, given a series of points (various locations), returns a series of weather values

```
{
    "latitude":[50.51, 52.52, 51.51, 53.52],
    "longitude":[-113.27, 179.41, -114.27, 178.41],
    "models": ["gem_hrdps_continental"],
    "hourly":["temperature_2m"]
}
```

As I am designing the component, these doubts came to me:

1. Should I leave the initial setting, i.e., enter only lat/lon (i.e., one point) and let the client handle a set of locations?
2. If my implementation choice (several points) has a reason, is it better to handle the error with a ResponseEntity that returns any errors. For example, in the input case above, two points are BAD_REQUESTs. So instead of generating a single error that blocks processing, this is done for the correct points, while for the incorrect points it returns an error message.

[image]

Comment: not sure i understood the question, just wanted to add some comments.. i think i would put the lat/lon in the same json object if i wanted to support multiple locations. and would probably add some identifier attribute as well, which i would add to the response so the client can use it to correlate weather/err responses a bit easier. but using multiple locations also depends on the actual endpoint you invoke. does it allow you to issue such "bulk" requests, or are you planning to invoke 1-by-1 and then merge them? in that case it would be more difficult to support multiple locations obviously.

Comment: endpoint does not allow "bulk" requests and I need to invoke 1-by-1